# Different implicit conversion in various std of C++

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

How to keep track of implicit conversions between different stds of C++?

I have a following code:

```
struct Conv;

struct Test {
    Test() { puts("def"); }
    explicit Test(Test const& ref) { puts("copy"); }
    explicit Test(Test&& ref) { puts("move"); }
    Test(int) { puts("int"); }
};

struct Conv {
    operator Test() const  {
        puts("operator Test()");
        return 6;
    }
};

int main() {
   Conv y;
   Test t = {y}; // copy list init
}
```

If compiled using std=c++14 clang, `error chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization`
But it compiles in std=c++17 clang and in std=c++20 clang

If I mark the conversion fn explicit,

```
explicit operator Test() const  {
            puts("operator Test()");
            return 6;
        }
```

in c++14 `error: no matching constructor for the initialization of Test`
But in c++17 and 20 it compiles.

Is there any rule to how implicit conversions are ordered between converting constructor and conversion functions?

Edit: In clang c++17 and c++20 it prints

```
operator Test()
int
```

In c++14 error as stated above

Comment: You might want to include what prints.  And look up the somewhat misnamed guaranteed elision.

Comment: C++17 changed the way copy elision works. You can `delete`  the copy/move ctors and it will still work in C++17 and up. They are not needed at all in the line marked with "copy". There is no copying, even logically. C++14 required them to be present and accessible because the operation was logically a copy construction.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the function in question is a conversion function. `Test t = some_function();` works the same way. There is no copying and no copy ctor us needed.